# Compare lists and get unique elements

Tags: c#

I have a object called Parent, and a list of objects called Child.
The Parent object has also a list of Child's.

```
public class Parent 
{
   public Parent() 
   {
      Children = new List<Child>();
   }

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

Now i want to get those Childrens from the list that doesnt exist in Parent's list of Children.

How can i acchieve this with linq/lambda expression?

The code i've tried without any success:

```
Parent parent = GetParent();
List<Child> children = GetChildren();

var notExistingChildren = children.Where(child => !parent.Children.Any(ch => ch.Name == child.Name)).ToList();
```

children have 1 element that doesnt exist in parent.Children, but this expression doesnt get that element and assign it to notExistingChildren.

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with your current approach? Can you provide names which (not) matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not very efficient, because you are enumerating parents children for each child in `children` collection. Also you can have problems if names have different case - e.g. `"Bob"` and `"bob"` are different strings in C#. But your approach should work if names are equal:

```
var notExistingChildren = 
    children.Where(c => !parent.Children.Any(pc => pc.Name == c.Name))
            .ToList();
```

More efficient and easy to read way is implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for `Child` class (or creating custom `IEqualityComparer` for `Child` class). In this case you will be able to use `Enumerable.Except` which performs set operation:

```
var notExistingChildren = children.Except(parent.Children).ToList();
```

If child name can be used as it's identity, then you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in following way:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Child other = obj as Child;
    if (other == null)
        return false;

    return other.Name == Name;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

---

BTW I tried your code with following sample data and it works fine - Joe is returned as non existing child.

```
List<Child> children = new List<Child>
{
    new Child { Name = "Bob" },
    new Child { Name = "Joe" }
};

Parent parent = new Parent
{
    Children = new List<Child> { new Child { Name = "Bob" } }
};
```

If you don't see some child in results, then child with same name exists in parents children collection. There is no other way.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've gone through every elements now (about 150) and found a match. But thanks for the alternative that is much more readable. I will use this instead.

Answer (score 0):

The expression works fine for me. Use ch.Name.ToLower() == child.Name.ToLower() for comparison as your lists may have different character cases

Comment: If you're going to try comparing strings by using `.ToLower()`, you should consider using the [String.Equals Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Selection of the correct `StringComparison` will give more reliable results.